# How to handle update_ops of batch normalization in Keras functional model API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, batch-normalization

I am trying out the functional API for Keras models and trying to set up two dataset streams using the same model and weight sharing, which also consists of batch normalization. When I create the model on top of my first datastream and then call it on the second datastream, I can see in the tensorboard the additional update ops, but the model does not include these newly created ops. My question would be, what a good coding approach would look like for this scenario, while still being able to use the classical tensorflow sessions, dataset iterators and custom losses and optimizers?

I've attached some code showing how my requested behavior actually works for the BatchNormalization layer itself. Still, it would be also nice in this case to have more control over the update ops, e.g. instead of iterating through the list and check the names, directly having somehow the update ops connected or returned with the call of the layer itself, so that one can associate directly the update ops to the correct datastream.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import shutil
import os.path as osp


shutil.rmtree(osp.join('/tmp', 'keras_model_testtb'), ignore_errors=True)
tb_saver = tf.summary.FileWriter(osp.join(
    '/tmp', 'keras_model_testtb',
))

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
batchnorm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
output1 = batchnorm(input1, training=tf.constant(True))
# following print shows:
# [
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>
# ]
print(batchnorm.updates)
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
output2 = batchnorm(input2, training=tf.constant(True))
# following print shows:
# [
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1_1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1_1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>
# ]
# update ops of both layer calls are merged into one list and one has to check the name of the ops
# to use them correctly with optimizers
print(batchnorm.updates)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    tb_saver.add_graph(session.graph)
```

Here is some sample code using the Keras Model API. As you can see, the model updates op do have the additional 2 update ops as in the previous example only for the case when using the keras Input layer. For dataset iterators it seems to do something different.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tensorflow as tf
import shutil
import os.path as osp


def reshape(sample):
    return tf.cast(tf.tile(sample[None, None, None], [2, 4, 3]), tf.float32)


ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
ds = ds.map(reshape)
input_ds = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()


shutil.rmtree(osp.join('/tmp', 'keras_model_testtb'), ignore_errors=True)
tb_saver = tf.summary.FileWriter(osp.join(
    '/tmp', 'keras_model_testtb',
))

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
output1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(input1, training=tf.constant(True))
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=output1)
# following prints show:
# [
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>
# ]
# []
print(model.updates)
print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if 'model' in n.name and 'AssignSubVariableOp' in n.name])
output_ds = model(input_ds)
# following prints show:
# [
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>
# ]
# ['model/batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp', 'model/batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp']
print(model.updates)
print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if 'model' in n.name and 'AssignSubVariableOp' in n.name])
# Above I expected to have found the new update ops also in model.updates, as is the case when you call the model on keras Input tensors:
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
output2 = model(input2)
# following prints show:
# [
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,
#   <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,
#   <tf.Operation 'model_1/batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,
#   <tf.Operation 'model_1/batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>
# ]
# [
#   'model/batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp', 'model/batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp',
#   'model_1/batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp', 'model_1/batch_normalization_v1/AssignMovingAvg_1/AssignSubVariableOp'
# ]
print(model.updates)
print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if 'model' in n.name and 'AssignSubVariableOp' in n.name])

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    tb_saver.add_graph(session.graph)
```